# How do you make a light streak like this one on Blender Internal?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

Full Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eNtjpurVwQ

I already tried searching here on stackexchange but can't find anything that is related to creating a light streak like this one.

Comment: A search for light streaks or light trails finds a few tutorials, like [this](http://www.creativeshrimp.com/how-to-create-light-trails-in-blender-traffic.html) or [this](http://www.blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/346-tutorial-light-streaks-in-blender.html)

Comment: I already watched blenderdiplom's video but I don't think the technique used for the result I want is taught. Didn't bother watching creativeshrimp's video because its cycles and the thumbnail is not close to what light streak I want. But I'll watch it later since you suggested it and it just might be the answer I'm looking for and try to find a way to implement on blender internal.

Comment: Why must you use internal?

Comment: I'm not using a good computer atm and you know how long renders are in cycles.

Comment: I clicked the picture to make the video play... and you too, admit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To animate the streak, create two curve objects. Shape the first one to be the shape of the extrusion, the second as the path that it will follow.

In the curve settings for the path select the other curve to be the Bevel Object, then animate the start and end of the bevel factor. You could also add a solidify modifier to get some thickness to the shape.

[image: bevel settings]

[image: streak sample]

As a starting point for the material, you want to have it emit a little and to be mostly transparent, you can add a texture to get the striped variation in transparency. For cycles use a mix node with an emission and a tranparent node.

[image: mat settings]

Add a glow in the compositor to finish off the effect, maybe some motion blur as well.